ASP.NET Core Identity InvalidUserName
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application that uses ASP.NET Core Identity. When I try to create a new user using the UserManager, I get this error:

User name ' ' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

Username do not has any whitespace.
When I try to create new user I get the error:
var user = new User
{
    Name = "my name",
    UserName = "GoodName",
    Email = "qwerty@gmail.com",
    EmailConfirmed = true
};

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "123723-Aa");

Code in program file:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
{
// User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<School.Database.SchoolContext>()
.AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

This is repo link:
https://github.com/MrMustafa-2/TestProject.git
And when you run the project go to this url:
/Account/Register
Then you can see the error at the Breakpoint I mark it
I am waiting ...
Thanks

@marc_s 123723-Aa is password

Yes, just for test code

I used your code but could not reproduce the problem. You can check whether the corresponding User entity is injected in your userManager dependency, and you can set a breakpoint on the CreateAsync method to check if there is a specific error message like Description = "Username 'GoodName1' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits." If your UserName field does not contain spaces at the beginning and end, and the error still cannot be solved, can you share your user model and dbcontext?

@Yuning Duan, I update the post - I upload the project, if it possible check it please

Since there is a custom UserName field in APPUser, this causes a duplication with the UserName of identityUser, so an invalid error occurs.

You can add an override attribute to Appuser to avoid this error, such as:
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
   
    public override string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
}

When I reinsert the data:
public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
{
    var user = new AppUser
    {
        Id="1",
        UserName = "johndoekk",
        Email = "johndoen@example.com",
        FirstName = "Jonhn",
        LastName = "Dnoe",
        Name = "John Dnoe"
    };

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "123123-Aa");

    int sfd = 4;

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return Ok();
}




References : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.useroptions.allowedusernamecharacters?view=aspnetcore-6.0
As per the above Microsoft official documentation,
AspNet_Users table's Username field default valid allowed characters are :
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+
As per your question you are using space in Username field like "any user name".
You have to use it like "any_user_name" or "anyusername" or you can just use characters from the above lists.
Still, you want to use space in your Username field, you can configure using AllowedUserNameCharacters property to modify default characters like this :
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<string>, IdentityRole>(options =>{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+/ ";
});


yep  for more details how this is working under the hood you can check https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/feedcb5c53444f716ef5121d3add56e11c7b71e5/src/Core/UserValidator.cs#L58

No, Username have no spaces, I updated my post and I added my code in Program class, but I get the same error: InvalidUserName

@MrMustafa022, In above code I added space character at the last. Please verify it. OR add the username you are using at run time for more clarification.

Yes, I test code with space character, but I get the same error: InvalidUserName

@MrMustafa022, Try without space character. Please check the above answered code carefully.

Trust me please, I tried with space and without space
